# Caps lock indicator does not work in kubuntu 12.04 w/ plasma workspace

Tags: capslock

Can anyone please tell how to enable the caps lock indicator in kubuntu 12.04... I tried installing indicator-keylock app but it says it no longer exists in the repository.. Is there an in built indicator for ubuntu? If so how to enable the same.

Thanks in advance for your kind answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keylock works for me. Type these commands in konsole:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```

Then go to *System setting*, *Startup and shutdown*, click `Add` program at autostart. Then browse to `/usr/share/bin/` and select `indicator-keylock` and finally reboot your system.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can try [plasma-widget-kbstate [image: Install plasma-widget-kbstate]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/plasma-widget-kbstate).

To install it, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-widget-kbstate
```